# Where to ask for an explanation about a code puzzle answer?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, asking-questions

Where can I ask for an explanation about [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169732/82125) to a Code Golf puzzle? I understand what the code does, but I just cannot figure out the logic/reasoning behind it, despite having read several articles about bitwise operations, checking if a number is a power of 2, etc. I know what a recursive function is. I just don't get why it has been used this way and why this works to answer to the puzzle.

Comment: You could simply comment on that answer to ask how it works.

Comment: I was going to ask a question in Code Golf, but as it's directly related to code, I then thought about posting it on SO. Hence this question. Also I didn't know there was a Code Golf specific meta, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a textbook case for a [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to me:

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author

Answer (score 1):

On [Codegolf Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/)

If you ask there, you're more than likely to get a great explanation of how something has worked from the people who write the answers.

Provided they visit Meta of course.